# How can I prepend and append to a request body with envoy proxy lua bodyChunks?

Tags: envoyproxy

I am using `envoy.filters.http.lua` and I would like to modify the request's body so that I can both prepend and append to the existing body. The simplest approach using `body()` is easy enough to implement :

```
local body = request_handle:body()
local bodyStr = "<a>" .. body:getBytes(0, body:length()) .. "<b>"
body:setBytes(bodyStr)
```

Now that solution doesn't seem enough to me because using `body()` forces the buffering of the whole contents of the body, leading to increased memory usage. For this reason, here's an attempt at using the `bodyChunks()` approach.

```
local last
local first = true
for chunk in request_handle:bodyChunks() do
  if first then
    chunkStr = "<a>" .. chunk:getBytes(0, chunk:length())
    chunk:setBytes(chunkStr)
    first = false
  end
  last = chunk
end
lastStr = last:getBytes(0, chunk:length()) .. "<b>"
last:setBytes(lastStr)
```

This attempt fails because it seems to send two different requests upstream. My guess is that the Content-Length header became wrong as soon as I appended/prepended characters as headers were already sent when I started accessing the body chunks. For this reason, here's another attempt where I try to modify the header.

```
request_handle:headers():replace("content-length", tostring(tonumber(request_handle:headers():get("content-length")) + 6))



local last
local first = true
for chunk in request_handle:bodyChunks() do
  if first then
    chunkStr = "<a>" .. chunk:getBytes(0, chunk:length())
    chunk:setBytes(chunkStr)
    first = false
  end
  last = chunk
end
lastStr = last:getBytes(0, chunk:length()) .. "<b>"
last:setBytes(lastStr)
```

As far as I can tell, the modifications I make are being overriden by calls to `setBytes` and after I start using `bodyChunks`, I can't replace the headers anymore. How should I modify the post body with the bodyChunks API? Is it possible?